# Multiple Dock Panels using DockPanelSuite and C#

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

Currently I am struggling having an `Dockpanel` inside a C# User Control Library because handling the MDI state is troublesome or not even possible...

Thus my question: is it even possible to have a MDI container inside another MDI container using Dockpanel-Suite? The best would be if the inner MDI container could be shipped as a shared library (This should be a User Control, shouldn't it?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the requirement using `DocumentStyle.DockingMdi` in the outer container and `DocumentStyle.DockingWindow` inside the inner container.

The result is fully functional but a bit ugly, so ... do not do it.